# How to fix segmentation error?

Tags: c

I wrote this simple program and when I run it, it says segmentation error. How do I fix it? Only the first line of program runs.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
int items;
float price, pprice, amt, HST;

printf("Enter the number of items :", items);
    scanf(" %d", items);

printf("Enter the unit price :", price);
    scanf(" %f", price);

pprice = items * price;
printf("Purchase price :pprice\n");

printf("HST (13%) : 1.64\n");
HST = 1.64;
amt = HST + pprice;

printf("Total price: amt\n\n");



return 0;
}
```

Comment: With a debugger. You fix it with a debugger.

Comment: And first of all, turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf(" %d", items);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %d", &items);
scanf(" %f", &price);
```

Provide the address of the variable.

Edits:

Your printf also has issue

```
printf("Enter the number of items :", items);
```

should be just

```
printf("Enter the number of items :");
```

and

```
printf("Enter the unit price : %f", price);
```

Please check the below link :

http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

Comment: Also OP's printf statements: `printf("Enter the number of items :", items)`<-- last argument

Comment: Also this line `printf("Purchase price :pprice\n");` should be `printf("Purchase price :%f\n", pprice);`, and ditto for two more similar lines.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes Yes Yes there are number of issue with this code :)

Answer (score 0):

segmentation error normally occurs when you donot use ampersand(&) for variables in scanf... so try attaching ampersand to the variable

like scanf(" %d",&items);